# How to set nginx proxy path to use static contents of a specific s3 bucket folder?

Tags: regex, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm working on an nginx reverse proxy container image to proxy frontend files from s3, and Im trying to access these files from a specific folder location, instead of just the base path of the s3 bucket. As of yet I can only serve up the index.html which I'm using a rewrite for, but I'm getting a 403 on the js and css files.

I've tried including mime.types

```
include       mime.types;
```

I've tried adding an s3 folder bucket param

```
proxy_pass http://YOURBUCKET.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/$1;
```

And then various regex options

Here is my nginx conf file

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen  443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/nginx-server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key   /etc/ssl/nginx-server.key;

    server_name timemachine.com;
    sendfile on;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    resolver        8.8.8.8;
    server_tokens   off;

    location ~ ^/app1/(.*) {
        set $s3_bucket_endpoint  "timemachineapp.s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com";
        proxy_http_version     1.1;
        proxy_buffering        off;
        proxy_ignore_headers   "Set-Cookie";
        proxy_hide_header      x-amz-id-2;
        proxy_hide_header      x-amz-request-id;
        proxy_hide_header      x-amz-meta-s3cmd-attrs;
        proxy_hide_header      Set-Cookie;
        proxy_set_header       Authorization "";
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        rewrite ^/app1/?$ /dev/app1/index.html;    <-- I can only access index.html and the other js and css files throw a 403
        proxy_pass https://timemachineapp.s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com;
        break;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to make this so that the user goes to https://timemachine/app1 that this will go to the homepage and load all the css and js files. Again, what im getting is a 403 and sometimes a 404. Insight appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question it looks like

- There's a constant request-url prefix `/app1/`
- There's a constant proxied-url prefix `/dev/app1/`

On that basis...

## First, enable the debug log

There will already be an `error_log` directive in the nginx config, locate it and temporarily change to debug:

```
error_log  /dev/stderr debug;
```

This will allow you to see how these requests are being processed.

## Try naive-simple first

Let's use this config (other header directives omitted for brevity):

```
location = /app1 { # redirect for consistency
    return 301 /app1/;
}

location = /app1/ { # explicitly handle the 'index' request
    proxy_pass https://example.com/dev/app1/index.html;
}

location /app1/ {
    proxy_pass https://example.com/dev/;
}
```

And emit a request to it:

```
$ ~ curl -I http://test-nginx/app1/some/path/some-file.txt
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
...
```

Note that S3 returns a 403 for requests that don't exist, nginx is just proxying that response here.

Let's look in the logs to see what happened:

```
2023/01/28 14:46:10 [debug] 15#0: *1 test location: "/"
2023/01/28 14:46:10 [debug] 15#0: *1 test location: "app1/"
2023/01/28 14:46:10 [debug] 15#0: *1 using configuration "/app1/"
...
"HEAD /dev/some/path/some-file.txt HTTP/1.0
Host: example.com
Connection: close
User-Agent: curl/7.79.1
Accept: */*
"
```

So our request became `https://example.com/dev/some/path/some-file.txt`

That's because the way [proxy_pass](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) works is:

> If the proxy_pass directive is specified with a URI, then when a request is passed to the server, the part of a normalized request URI matching the location is replaced by a URI specified in the directive

Meaning:

```
Nginx receives:
/app1/some/path/some-file.txt
      ^ the normalized path starts here

Proxied-upstream receives:
/dev/some/path/some-file.txt
     ^ and was appended to proxy-pass URI
```

I point this out as renaming/moving things on s3 may lead to a simpler nginx setup.

## Rewrite all paths, not specific requests

Modifying the config above like so:

```
location = /app1 { # redirect for consistency
    return 301 /app1/;
}

location = /app1/ { # explicitly handle the 'index' request
    proxy_pass https://example.com/dev/app1/index.html;
}

location /app1/ {
    rewrite ^/(.*) /dev/$1 break;             # prepend with /dev/
    # rewrite ^/app1/(.*) /dev/app1/$1 break; # OR this
    proxy_pass https://example.com/;          # no path here
}
```

And trying that test-request again yields the following logs:

```
"HEAD /dev/app1/some/path/some-file.txt HTTP/1.0
Host: example.com
Connection: close
User-Agent: curl/7.79.1
Accept: */*

"
```

In this way the index request works, but also arbitrary paths - and there's no need to modify this config to handle each individual url requested.

Comment: this is helpful. Thanks for the detailed the response. Also, idk if this matters, but Im not using cloudfront for this. So I was assuming the proxy_pass had to be the s3 bucket. So basically I was aiming for this:  

user the following and this opens the site: 
https://timemachin/app1  

The s3 reverse proxy forwards requests to s3 (shouldn't this be what is happening under the hood?):
https://timemachineapp.s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/index.html

Comment: Using cloudfront or not is not a factor. Where the thing is you are proxying is hosted is not relevant to nginx, nginx only cares that the upstream exists. Note the domain in your posts and comments (`timemachineapp.s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com`) does not resolve, you can get the correct domain from the aws console (i.e. look at the Object URL for any object).

Comment: Its still not working. Im getting a mime type error saying I can't load js files. I add default type and it still doesnt load them.

Comment: How do you do this if your proxy_pass is an internal https bucket w/ internal routes? Is there a way to get all paths on a base path because I can't just set index index.html or try_files. Nothing is saved in a container and there's no path set in s3

Comment: `default_type` has no bearing on proxied responses - it's for static files. If the content-type header is missing on s3, that's the thing to fix using `aws s3 cp` sets the content type automatically afaik, so the problem is how those files are being uploaded. This is one new question :)

Comment: Likewise `try_files` is _also_ for static files and not relevant to proxying content. Bear in mind to proxy x successfully, x needs to work - i.e. in principle you should be able to load `http://YOURBUCKET.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/dev/index.html` in a browser, if it doesn't fix _that_, there should be no need for anything none-trivial in nginx.  `is an internal https bucket w/ internal routes?` I don't know what this means, but proxying files on s3 is the same as proxying files from anywhere. Please also treat as a new question (research, and if necessary ask)

Comment: The server name is a typical dns record with cert. The proxy pass for the S3 bucket where the files are uploaded is only internally accessible to the specific vpc with iam permissions on the bucket. The static content uploaded to s3 is the content in the dist folder of angular apps after build. These have virtual paths/modules though. The other part of this is that all of this is behind an application load balancer. I’ve got two routes on the alb. /app1 which redirects to host://app1/ and then another route path /app1/* which forwards requests to the nginx TG using this container to proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so found a solution. Unless I'm missing something, this is easier than thought. For my use case, all I had to do was simply add multiple writes with those css files passed in (I'm sure there's a simpler way to just specify any .css file extension regardless of the naming of the file. Anyway, here is solution at the moment:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen  443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/nginx-server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key   /etc/ssl/nginx-server.key;

    server_name timemachine.com;
    sendfile on;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    resolver        8.8.8.8;
    server_tokens   off;

    location ~ ^/app1/(.*) {
        set $s3_bucket_endpoint  "timemachineapp.s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com";
        proxy_http_version     1.1;
        proxy_buffering        off;
        proxy_ignore_headers   "Set-Cookie";
        proxy_hide_header      x-amz-id-2;
        proxy_hide_header      x-amz-request-id;
        proxy_hide_header      x-amz-meta-s3cmd-attrs;
        proxy_hide_header      Set-Cookie;
        proxy_set_header       Authorization "";
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        rewrite ^/app1/?$ /dev/app1/index.html;   
        rewrite ^/app1/?$ /dev/app1/cssfile.css;  <- and keep adding, if needed
        proxy_pass https://timemachineapp.s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: what are those identical rewrite directives intended to do?

Comment: When a user enters a url path with /app1 (this just being an example app placeholder string), the regex matches that string and adds the bucker folder, along with the app name, to access those static files in the s3 /dev folder. Since Im not copying static files into the docker container on docker build, but proxying the files from s3, I can't access them in a way that's typical with nginx by setting root or something like that. That said, im still getting an error when access the css files, so it only works for the index.html currently and then bails when trying to load .css or .js files.

Comment: This container is being deployed behind a load balancer also so im mapping the same route path on the ALB as well (i..e, /app1)

Comment: I'll write an answer with a suggestion but my comment relates to this: `and keep adding, if needed` - this rule is unreachable and as such not doing anything.

Comment: Correct, I looked at s3 again in aws and noticed that I had two sets of the "app1" static files, one in the /dev folder and the other in root of the bucket, so it was accessing those files from the root bucket location. After removing those files, the app failed to the js and css files.